# Calculation of an integral on the unit disk

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate the integral $\int_D xy^3+y^2 \ dA$ on the unit disk $x^2+y^2\leq 1$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

$$x=r\cos \theta , \ y=r\sin \theta, \ r^2=x^2+y^2\leq 1$$ $$0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi , 0\leq r \leq 1$$

So, $$\int_D xy^3+y^2 \ dA=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (r\cos\theta \ r^3\sin^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta)rdrd\theta \\ =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (r^4\cos\theta\sin^3\theta+r^3\sin^2\theta)drd\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} \left (\frac{1}{5}\cos\theta\sin^3\theta+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2\theta\right )d\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Aside from a typo at the second integral (should be $r\cos\theta r^3\sin^\color{red}{3}\theta$, everything looks fine.

Comment: Oh yes... Thank you very much!! :-) @achillehui

Comment: Isn't it $r^5 \cos \theta \sin^3 \theta$ in the first summand?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right!! But the result is then the same, isn't it? @michael

Comment: I think so, the first term is zero anyway

Comment: Ok... Thanks a lot!! :-) @michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug that did not affect the result:
 $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (r\cos\theta \ r^3\sin^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta)rdrd\theta \\ =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (r^5\cos\theta\sin^3\theta+r^3\sin^2\theta)drd\theta=\int_0^{2\pi} \left (\frac{1}{6}\cos\theta\sin^3\theta+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2\theta\right )d\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar, You are welcome! )